# DLL load failed while importing _libheif_cffi on Windows

Tags: python

I'm using Python 3.11.4 on Windows 11. Following the [instructions](https://github.com/carsales/pyheif/issues/2#issuecomment-886469620), I managed to install `pyheif`. When `import pyheif`, it raises the error

```
DLL load failed while importing _libheif_cffi. The specified module could not be found
```

`pyheif` is under `c:\src\p3venv\lib\site-packages\`. I tried to find out where `_libheif_cffi` is.

```
import importlib.util
importlib.util.find_spec('_libheif_cffi')
```

It prints

```
ModuleSpec(name='_libheif_cffi', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x0000...>, origin='C:\\src\p3venv\\lib\\site-packages\\_libheif_cffi.pyd')
```

`C:\\src\p3venv\\lib\\site-packages\\_libheif_cffi.pyd` does exist and `file _libheif_cffi.pyd` prints `_libheif_cffi.pyd: PE32+ executable (DLL) (GUI) x86-64, for MS windows, 6 sections`.

In a related question, an answer suggests that with Python 3.8 and above in order to load dlls, `os.add_dll_directory('/path/to/dlldir/')` is necessary. So, I tried

```
import os
os.add_dll_directory('C:\\src\p3venv\\lib\\site-packages\\')
```

It prints `<AddedDllDirectory('C:\\src\p3venv\\lib\\site-packages\\')>`. However, `import pyheif` still raises the same error.

Thanks for any help.